# Dim Lights/Change Colors button with Javascript/html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a website (mainly html/css). I would like to incorporate a button that when clicked changes the background color/image of the page. How do I do this can you help me with the code necessary? I believe this can be done in html/javascript. Thank You.

Comment: i suggest you read about a fine library called [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) and especially about it's [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function

Comment: I suggest you don't dive right into JQuery and instead learn the fundamentals of Javascript first. That way, you'll know what the language is capable of, and you won't make the mistake so many young developers make of using frameworks for every trivial task they run into. You'll also learn the proper usage of web technologies, such as the importance of separating styles from content from logic, and the dangers of XSS attacks overlooked in almost all JS libraries today. Once you know all these things, by all means, use frameworks, within reason, to avoid the nasty browser inconsistencies.

Comment: This is a learning forum, Kindly do not vote down if the question is simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can pure javascript `document.body.style.backgroundImage`

```
<input type="button" onclick="changeBackground();" />

<img src="../images/someimage.png" onclick="changeBackground();" />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function changeBackground()
        {
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../images/yourimage.png)';
        }
</script>
```

Comment: @Soup Gill : yes you can use image.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Also if i were to use the button to change the wallpaper, how would I use attributes such as background-attachment: fixed; to edit the placement of this wallpaper

Comment: Call the Javascript function `changeBackground()` (mentioned in Govind's answer) or `changeBG()` (mentioned in my answer) on onclick event of an image.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use Javascript as used in this Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/NZwGb/

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Change BG Image" onclick="changeBG();" /><br />

OR<br />

<img src="http://www.naturewallpaper.co.uk/wallpapers/nature-wallpaper-90.jpg" width="200px;" onclick="changeBG();">
```

**Javascript**

```
function changeBG() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-C6ZUDP_SUjo/T90hd_j90qI/AAAAAAAAADw/I2fhPhJcS-8/s1600/Nature+river+sun.jpg)';
}
```